# Using Java's ternary operator, what's the implication of assigning a variable to itself?

Tags: java, performance, variables, variable-assignment, ternary

I make excessive use of the ternary operator, sometimes even replacing very simple if statements with it. For example, I just found myself replacing something like this:

```
if (foo != null) {
    bar = foo;
}
```

with this:

```
bar = (foo == null) ? bar : foo;
```

While it is a question of taste which one reads nicer, I am wondering:

- **In this case, is the ternary version's performance worse?**
- **Are there any other reasons against the use of ternary here?**

The reason why I belive the performance could be worse here is that I assume the compiler can't optimize the ternary for when `foo` is `null`. Hence, the value of `bar` might be set to the same value again, wasting some CPU time, where the simple `if` statement would never get to that point. But my knowledge of compilers and execution is limited, hence the question.

Comment: The idea of something that "collapses" in certain conditions into `bar = bar` is weird to me.  The former (with the `if` statement) is more verbose, but much more readable and clear.  My $0.02

Comment: you have already answered your own question. that's "overhead" and inexpedient usage of the ternary operator.

Comment: Why would it be different from assigning `i = i`, for any other variable?

Comment: Creating a do-nothing self-assignment is code smell. Ternary operators are designed for reducing the bloat of an if-else assignment. If there's no else, it doesn't really need to be used.

Comment: There is a use for the ternary operator similar to this where you have a conditional assignment `a = (a == null) ? b : a;` where you assign `a` to `b` if `a` is null.

Comment: Somewhat tangential to your point, worrying about the compile/run time differences between those two statements is probably more trouble than it's worth.  I think it's more of interest to make sure your code is completely coherent in its operation than to worry about a few microseconds of operations.  For instance, will someone down the road think "why the sweet Christmas is there a ternary operation here"?  If so, probably use the standard idiom.  Seconds of a developers time > Microseconds of processing time, in most cases.

Comment: It's impossible to say a-priori because even if we just go ahead and *assume* that the second way results in a conditional move rather than a branch, that is neither strictly worse nor strictly better than a branch. It depends. But we can't even assume that, so we know even less than that.

Comment: Yeah... I overuse the ternary operator quite a bit myself (often with nested, multi-line things), but that still looks weird to me. To me the advantage is the compiler-checked guarantee that a value is returned in any branch, and the fact that it lets me distinguish "functional" constructs from "imperative" ones. I don't see yours doing that, though... maybe if you used this in the initial assignment to `bar`, instead?

Comment: Also note that collapsing the if statement onto a single line is less verbose,  more efficient (if however slightly, since that seems to be of concern), and closer to the standard idiom than using the ternary operation.  Really can't see a reasonable argument to use a ternary operation like this.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments; it helped me make up my mind. I'm going with `if` and will do so for similar pieces of code in the future as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've worried about style, you should at least remove the bracket noise:

```
bar = foo == null ? bar : foo;
```

As for performance, you have an unnecessary assignment in the case that `foo` is null. Big deal. You're talking about nanoseconds.

Don't worry about this insignificant difference of "performance". Worry about readability, which is more important.

In this case, I find the `if` version more readable:

```
if (foo != null) {
    bar = foo;
}
```

It's very clear what the intention of the code is.

Comment: Thinking about it, one reason that made me go with ternary here is that I prefer `foo == null` over `foo != null`. Also, I agree that the difference in performance won't matter in most cases; just wanted to know for sure nevertheless. What I disagree with is the bracket-less ternary: I find it way easier to read with brackets. But that is, of course, a matter of taste and habit. By the way, I changed my code to the `if` version as I agree that it is easiest to read (and have now been reassured that the ternary one might add some nanoseconds).

Comment: @domdom regarding `foo == null` vs `foo != null`, always prefer *positive* tests (ie equal to, greater than, etc) over *negative* tests (not equal to, not greater than, etc) if you can, because they are easier for our tiny human brains to read and comprehend.